# Calculate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln{\left(\sin{x}\right)}\ln{\left(\cos{x}\right)}}{\tan x} dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to calculate the following integral
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln{\left(\sin{x}\right)}\ln{\left(\cos{x}\right)}}{\tan x} dx$$

Preferably as fast as possible as it showed up in an integration bee in which you only have 3-4 minutes to solve.

Comment: Outsourcing your problem isn't how you do competitions :P

Comment: @Kenny: I think he means the intended solution shouldn't be overly cumbersome.

Comment: Yes I saw it online in a challenging integral pdf meant for contest preparation and no solution was given.

Comment: @amWhy Hello, I generally go to these math challenges (which are for fun) and see what I can do under the time limit and the rest of the problems I try to work on when I get back home. Every so often I come across one that even after taking home and working on it for a while I still can't figure out. That is usually when I resort to the internet to figure out how to do. The problem is that I find solutions to some problems through means that clearly could not have been possible in the competition itself, for example partial fraction decomposition with multiple square root terms.

Comment: ... these kinds of problems are the ones I wish the "filter out" by asking for a "quick" method. Until recently I was not aware that this is against the rules, but from now on I will try to describe the situation more clearly in my problems.

Comment: At least attempt to provide more context, which is expected from all askers.  Show one solution you came up with.  Show an attempt at an approach, but end up stuck.... Just don't ask us to do work for you, when there is nothing from you indicating effort/context, etc.

Comment: @amWhy Yes in the future I will add additional details, unlike my previous posts.

Comment: @amWhy: outsourcing competition problems is fine as long as it isn’t during the competition. It would be no different than telling someone who is self-studying they weren’t allowed to ask questions (in both scenarios, the OP is trying to challenge themselves and cane across something he/she couldn’t solve alone). As for the use of “quick” in the post: again, it seems what is being asked is really an efficient solution instead of a solution that takes 3 pages worth of writing (in competitions, you want efficient solutions).

Comment: @amWhy: late? You made the comment two days after I had made mine... also, regarding context: my comment said nothing regarding context, only alluded to the fact that “quick” was not intended to mean an answer “right now” but a method of solution that shouldn’t be too cumbersome.

Comment: By the way just to be clear, I never ask for solutions to problems during the competitions in which they are asked (and I never would).

Comment: JayJuly  We understand that. No worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln{\left(\sin{x}\right)}\ln{\left(\cos{x}\right)}}{\tan x} dx&\stackrel{t=\sin x}= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln{t}\ln{\left(1-t^2\right)}}{t} d t\\&=-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^{1} t^{2n-1} \ln t ~dt\end{align}$$

---

It's well known and can be shown easily that:

$$\int_0^1 t^a \ln t~ dt = -\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}$$

Thus:

$$\int_0^{1} t^{2n-1} \ln t ~dt=-\frac{1}{4n^2}$$

---

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln{\left(\sin{x}\right)}\ln{\left(\cos{x}\right)}}{\tan x} dx=-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left(-\frac{1}{4n^2} \right)=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}=\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}$$

Comment: Thank you, this answer is perfect!